# Conditional statement coming up as unsigned

Tags: c, integer, variable-assignment, unsigned

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define Const_value sizeof(int)

int i = 100;
int j;
int main(){
    j = (Const_value - i > 0);
    printf("%ld, %d, %d",Const_value, i, j);
    return 0;
}
```

If I know that "Const_value" is 4 and "i" is 100 then the difference is -96. The expected outcome of j would be 0 in that case because -96 > 0 is a false statement and yet when this program is compiled and executed, j = 1. I assume it's because -96 is being treated as an unsigned value during the calculation but I fail to see any syntax that would indicate such a thing.

If I were to tweak the program into something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define Const_value sizeof(int)

int i = 100;
int j;
int main(){
    int x = Const_value - i;
    j = (x > 0);
    printf("%ld, %d, %d",Const_value, i, j);
    return 0;
}
```

Then I would get the expected result. What's the catch?

Outputs:

```
4, 100, 1
4, 100, 0
```

Comment: The first code does calculation using `size_t` which causes `((size_t)-96)` being a large unsigned value. Assigning it to an `int` in your second code forces it to be an `int` with value `-96`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Const_value` macro evaluates to a `size_t` which is an unsigned value with rank equal to or higher than `int`. So, the result is unsigned.

Specifically, the result will be a `size_t` value. In other words, the `i` is implicitly promoted to `size_t` via the [integer promotion rules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Integer_promotions), and then `Const_value - i` has unsigned overflow, wrapping the value around to a very large positive value. This then tests greater than zero.

Comment: That may explain the first program. What's stopping the casting to unsigned occurring for the second program, specifically for the variable 'x'?

Comment: Nothing is stopping that. But the result is then _converted_ to `int`. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Integer_conversions ... Turning up your compiler's warning level will usually identify conversions to a type with a smaller range.

Comment: `i` is converted, not promoted, to `size_t` by the *usual arithmetic conversions*, not by the *integer promotions*. The integer promotions never change an `int` and would not change an `int` to a `size_t`.

Comment: “Unsigned overflow” is a misnomer. The C standard defines overflow to be when the **defined** result of an operation is not representable in the result type, and it **defines** unsigned operations to wrap. This is important because when overflow does occur, the behavior is not defined by the C standard, whereas when wrapping occurs, the behavior is defined. (For example, if `a` and `b` are signed integer types, the defined result of `a*b` is the ordinary arithmetic product, so, if it is not representable, there is overflow. if they are unsigned, the defined result is the wrapped product.)